# Create a popup with radio box using js

Tags: javascript

First of all, I'm just a rookie with few knowledge on java script

I wanna create a pop up with three radio button on it, let's say, A, B, and C

How can I make it, can anybody help me out?

Answer (score 1):

include jQuery and jQuery UI in your application( will make this much easier).

In your HTML page HEAD section say:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#dialog" ).dialog();
    });
    </script>
```

In your HTML BODY say:

```
<div id="dialog" title="Radio Dialog">
    <input type='radio' value='A' name='myRadio'>A
    <input type='radio' value='B' name='myRadio'>B
    <input type='radio' value='C' name='myRadio'>C
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use the native JS `alert` or `confirm` methods to include radio buttons, they are for text purposes only. If you want custom pop-ups, use either something like jQuery UI (as Joshua mentioned above), or better, just craft it yourself. Make a `div' with radio-buttons inside, add appropriate CSS to design it, then keep it in the HTML limbo without attaching it. Bind the attachment to your event of choice.