# create a pop-up window and display a list of radio buttons using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup, radio-button

I'm writing on a js file.
Here is what I've tried so far. (My code is a bit long but here is what I'm trying to do)

```
var popUpList= $ ('<input type="radio">A<br> <input type="radio">B<br> <input type="radio">C');

var showPopUpButton=$('<button type="button">Select a Letter</button>'); 
// showPopUpButton is appended to the body
showPopUpButton.click(function() {
      alert(popUpList);
   });
```

When I click on showPopUpButton, the alert window shows [object Object], which I guess means that the variable popUpList is empty.
I couldn't find how to do that in javascript.

I also tried with jQuery as suggested here [Create a popup with radio box using js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11958531/create-a-popup-with-radio-box-using-js)

```
var popUpList= $ ('<input type="radio">A<br> <input type="radio">B<br> <input type="radio">C ');
    showPopUpButton.click(function() {
          popUpList.dialog();
       });
```

Now, the buttons are displayed but not inside a pop-up window! And they are all superposed. 
Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to wrap your `<input>`s in a container element, e.g.: `<div>`, because `dialog()` works on a single element.

In your code, you are asking the `dialog()` function to work on multiple DOM objects and thus it will fail.

Here is the code:

```
var popUpList = $('<div><input type="radio">A<br><input type="radio">B<br><input type="radio">C</div>');

showPopUpButton.click(function() {
    popUpList.dialog();
});
```

See it in action [here](http://jsfiddle.net/9rRdu/). Try it yourself. :)

Answer (score 0):

Changed your inputs to HTML string, parsing as HTML and inserting inside the #dialog element.

```
var popUpList= '<input type="radio">A<br> <input type="radio">B<br> <input type="radio">C',
    dialogHtml = $.parseHTML(popUpList);


showPopUpButton.click(function() {      
      $( "#dialog" ).html(dialogHtml).dialog();
   });
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Christopher Marshall. But nothing is showing ! I do have to add id="dialog" in the html line right? Anyway, with this id or not, the pop-up window is still not showing

Comment: Yes, your selector is referencing a div with the id of dialog. So <div id="dialog"></div>, Check your console for any errors and make sure you're loading jQuery UI

Comment: The console is not showing any error and I do have jQuery UI. I even tried with a simple html message  var test= $ ('<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog"><p>This is a test'); It still doesn't work

Comment: Checkout cychois answer :}